# How do i convert to different datatypes in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, converters

I am new to C# and am trying some things in a console application. I am trying to get the userinput and convert it to the different datatypes and then display the converted data.

I tried this so far:

```
string  userInput;
int     intInput;
float   floatInput;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
userInput = Console.ReadLine();

intInput = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
floatInput = (float)intInput;


Console.WriteLine("String input: "+userInput+"\n");
Console.WriteLine("Integer input: " + intInput + "\n");
Console.WriteLine("Float input: " + floatInput + "\n");
```

It doesn't give me any errors in visual studios, but when i run the program it likes integer numbers and displays them. But when I input a number like `4.4` it stops the program with a warning `FormatException was unhandled` for this line `inInput = convert.ToInt32(userInput);`.

My locals window shows:

```
userInput = "4.4"
intInput = 4
floatInput = 4.0
```

Why am I getting this error? Is this the correct way to convert datatypes?

edit: because I don't know what the user might input how can I test it somehow?

Comment: `floatInput = Convert.ToSingle(userInput);`

Answer (score 3):

**Error**

You are getting this error because "4.4" is not a value that represents an Integer, hence it cannot be converted.

The following is a great article for gaining a better understanding of the basic data types and typical values:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm

**Converting**

Be aware that there are a few ways to handle the task you've set out to achieve here of 'converting' a string to another data type.

For Integers, for example, you could use TryParse:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

TryParse would not raise an exception and break your app as this has.

**Handling Exceptions**

Also note, 'unhandled' here means that your code does not handle this kind of error, which it could have - with appropriate Try Catch blocks:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0yd65esw.aspx

Wrapping potentially erroneous code with Try Catch blocks allows you to handle an exception more gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

4.4 is not an integer, it's (perhaps) a decimal.

If you'd like to accept decimal input, you'll need to change your variable's type, and then use Convert.ToDecimal instead.

Answer (score 0):

datatype test="xyz"; // datatype- int, float..

datatype.TryParse(variable, out test);

if(test=="xyz")
//parsing can be done